# Add imageView to coordinatorLayout

Tags: android, layout, imageview, android-coordinatorlayout

Here is my coordinator layout. Everything is ok, I can see everything.

But I can't see the ImageView. In code I am initializing ImageView correctly and have an object. I need Image view in center of screen.

If I change ImageView to button I see button in center of screen, but if I change to something other I can´t seen that element.

Please how Can I add ImageView to coordinatorLayout?

This code is in coordinatorlayout.

Thank you.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/status_btn"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/red" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Smazat"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<include
    layout="@layout/panel_camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<!--height a width se nastavuje dynamicky-->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header_vg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/vision_bottom_sheet_header_height"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/gray_header_vision"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header_tv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/vision_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header_vg"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/empty_vg"
            layout="@layout/panel_vision_tutorial"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/vision_bottom_sheet_item_height"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header_vg" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is my panel_camera_preview:

```
<my_package.CameraSourcePreview
android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

<my_package.GraphicOverlay
    android:id="@+id/face_overlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</my_package.CameraSourcePreview>
```

Comment: Please provide your whole layout including CoordinatorLayout.

Comment: Sorry, I edit my question. I need Image view in center of screen.
If I change ImageView to button I see button in center of screen, but if I change to something other I can´t seen that element. @Drv

Comment: provide your `panel_camera_preview` layout..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoordinatorLayout is a FrameLayout, thus the last View in order overlays the previous ones. Then Imageview results not visible because it is covered by your *panel_camera_preview*, while Button results visible, but only if is running on Lollipop or greater, cause its default elevation (2dp).